# Map a String 2D array to a new object using Stream

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have a POJO Traveller with variables String name, String city. I have a string array like

```
List<String[]>  events = Arrays
            .asList(new String[][] { { "Person A", "City 1" },{ "Person A", "City 1" }, { "Person A", "City 2" }, { "Person B", "City 1" },
                    { "Person B", "City 3" }, { "Person C", "City 2" }, { "Person C", "City 4" } });
```

I want a map with the name as key and list of cities.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = events.stream().map(traveller ->  Traveller :: new).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Traveller::getName));
```

I am not able to map to the Traveller. Is there a way to map to the Traveller and to get  the name as key and list of cities.

Comment: do you want to map string array to object ?

Comment: I dont want to map to the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Traveller::new` is not correct to create an Object from an array, your way is not correct, instead you have to use :

```
Map<String, List<Traveller>> map = events.stream()                   
        .map(traveller -> new Traveller(traveller[0], traveller[1])) // 1
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Traveller::getName));         // 2
```

1. Create a constructor in your class, which hold city and name
2. Group with name
3. the result of the grouping is `Map<String, List<Traveller>>` not `Map<String, List<String>>`

---

From the OP [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052369/map-a-string-2d-array-to-a-new-object-using-stream#comment104344942_59052435) :

> I want as the result a map with name of person as key and list of
>   cities as the value

In this case you have to use :

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = events.stream()
        .map(traveller -> new Traveller(traveller[0], traveller[1]))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Traveller::getName, 
                Collectors.mapping(Traveller::getCity, Collectors.toList())));
```

But instead, I would not go with the way of creating `events`, instead I would use `Traveller` instead of `List<String[]>`

```
List<Traveller> events = Arrays.asList(new Traveller("Person A", "City 1"), new Traveller("Person A", "City 1"),
        new Traveller("Person A", "City 2"), new Traveller("Person B", "City 1"),
        new Traveller("Person B", "City 3"), new Traveller("Person C", "City 2"), new Traveller("Person C", "City 4"));
```

Then you can just use :

```
Map<String, List<String>> collect = events.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Traveller::getName,
                Collectors.mapping(Traveller::getCity, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Assuming `Traveller` got a constructor with 2 parameters.

Comment: Yes @Amongalen I was writing, I don't finish my answer

Comment: I want as the result a map with name of person as key and list of cities as the value

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the advantage of converting it into `Traveller` object, So you can directly perform grouping by using `Collectors.groupingBy` based on name in array and `Collectors.mapping` to map `Cities (List<String>)` as values

```
Map<String, List<String>> res = events.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(key -> key[0].split(" ")[1],
            Collectors.mapping(val -> val[1].split(" ")[1], Collectors.toList())));
```